# addEventListner is triggerd before the HTMLElement is clicked

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm using an addEventListner method on a HTMLElement inside a function that is called on onLoad. However, the method gets executed even before i try the click event in the html page.

```
        function setConfigurationMenu(){

            var navConfigure = document.querySelector(".navConfigure");
            var navBody = navConfigure.querySelector(".body");
            var navTop = navConfigure.querySelector(".top");

            navTop.addEventListener("click", alert("jow"));

        }
```

So what's going on here, any ideas?

thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are executing the `alert` function and passing its *return value* (which is `undefined`) as parameter to the `addEventListener` method. You actually need to pass a function to it.

```
navTop.addEventListener("click", functionToBeTriggered);
```

As `alert` expects a parameter that is your text, you might want to wrap it into an anonymous function that calls it. For example:

```
navTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("jow")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you pass function `result` instead of function `handler`, try anonymous function for this:

```
navTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("jow");
});
```

In other words in your case you just invoke function, but you need to pass handler for this.